# asp.net mvc posting form values using html.actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how can i post the form values using html.actionlink, don't want to use routes dictionary

<%=Html.ActionLink("Download", "MyFiles", "Jobs", null, new { @class = "cvclick" })%>

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

A link points to an HTTP GET request.
An HTTP GET request is sent to a URL; the URL must be defined using a route.

Answer (score 2):

To POST values you could use an HTML form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("MyFiles", "Jobs")) { %>
    <%= Html.Hidden("key1", "value1") %>
    <%= Html.Hidden("key2", "value2") %>
    <input type="submit" value="Download" />
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

To POST values you could use Spark View Engine and a HTML form:

```
<form action="myfiles" controller="jobs">
  <hidden name="key1" value="value1" />
  <hidden name="key2" value="value2" />
  <submit title="Download" />
</form>
```

(The code uses some pretty standard bindings that be wired in Spark)

As for links and ActionLink. I would use the ajax helper instead since it can POST stuff. (`Ajax.ActionLink`)

**Edit**

So you want to DOWNLOAD a file? Well. The link should point on an action in your controller. The action should return a `FileResult` with your file. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: using ajax.actionlink is there a way to return file

Comment: Nope. You gotto use forms to return files. but you can use a link (and the `onclick` attribute) to submit a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can post the data using :-

anthing inside Beginform will be posted

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName"))
{ %>

 texbox code 

   <input type="submit" class="dASButton" value="Submit" />

 <% } %>
```